# Python Sum of Squares Function

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm having troubles with this last question. It's from the book "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist". Could you guys help me with this?

**Write a function sum_of_squares_of_digits that computes the sum of the squares of the digits of an integer passed to it. For example,sum_of_squares_of_digits(987) should return 194, since 9**2 + 8**2 + 7**2 == 81 + 64 + 49 == 194.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the integer to a string, then the individual characters back to integers:

```
def sum_of_squares_of_digits(value):
    return sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(value))
```

This uses `sum()` together with a generator expression to turn all the digits back to integers, square them, and sum the results together again.

Demo:

```
>>> def sum_of_squares_of_digits(value):
...     return sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(value))
... 
>>> sum_of_squares_of_digits(987)
194
```

Comment: you told him to try it on his own then you gave him a super-concise nice answer... for shame, lol

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I gave the concise pythonic answer. The OP will, unfortunately, not learn anything from this, because they haven't tried anything themselves.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using this as a reference to get my answer. It does make more sense now though actually. Thanks to all answerers.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the digits of a number by converting it into a string:

```
>>> n = 102
>>> for digit in str(n):
...     print(digit)
... 
1
0
2
```

`digit` will still be a string, so you can use `int(digit)` to turn it into an integer.